Media index on DSM 7.2 runs forever
From some time now, the media index on my Synology DS1019+ keeps running forever. As I can tell, it is meant to generate photo and video thumbs but it stays at zero.
I deleted all the photos I had under the photo folder but the process keeps running.
In the Log Center, it says it cannot start Media Indexing.
This is what the UI says with the circle running -
Log Center line
I reinstalled DSM (DSM 7.2.1-69057 Update 5) but still the same.
Any help on how to stop this behaviour and normally start Media Indexing?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
